# Using storage access framework to create a file

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Recently I received a crash report from a user who tried to create a backup of a database using the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) on a lollipop device.

Exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CREATE_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* (has extras) }
```

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Backup.db");
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_BACKUP_SAF);
```

**Qestion:**

Do all v19+ devices really support the Storage Access Framework?
How should we handle such cases?

**[UPDATE]**

Received 4 additional crash reports from different devices.

Comment: "Do all v19+ devices really support the Storage Access Framework?" -- it's part of standard Android AFAIK. Perhaps this device was running some messed-up ROM mod.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your comment! Yes it is part of standard Android API. But I have received two more identical crash reports. All reported from different devices.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it may be useful for somebody else that had the same problem, so here it is how I solved my problem

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Backup.db");
intent.setType("*/*");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_BACKUP_SAF);
} else {
    // start my custom file browser...
}
```